# Notation of vectors

Tags: vectors, notation

It's very common to see $\text{F} = 30 \text{ N}$ when the problem is unidimensional. Yet, force is a vector. Shouldn't I write $|\overrightarrow{F}| = 30 \text{ N}$? Because if I write $\overrightarrow{F} = 30 \text{ N}$ I'm saying that the vector is equal to an scalar. On the other hand, I rarely see $\overrightarrow{F} = (30, 0, 0)$.

Comment: $F$ is widely used as shorthand for $|\vec{F}|$.

Comment: Also note that $F$ can be negative in 1D, e.g. $F=-30N$. This means that the force is pointing in the negative x direction, but has a magnitude of $30N$. So in this case we have to distinguish between $F$ and $|F|$

Comment: @mrblick  That's exactly why writing $F$ for $|\vec{F}|$ is not such a good idea.  Although it is widely used.  Personally, I prefer to write an arrow over a symbolic representation of a vector, and I use subscripts for components.  But for 1-d cases, that's awkward and I end up using the ambiguous notation.

Comment: @garyp I agree, it's just used so frequently especially in intro mechanics courses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, you should not write "$\left|\vec{F}\right| = 30\textrm{N}$", because it's no better than "$F=30\textrm{N}$"

Since force is a vector, you could write out the list of components, either as a parenthetical list or a column vector:
$$\vec{F} = \left(30\textrm{N}\right) = \left[ 30\textrm{N}\right]$$

You could also write the one component as a scalar:
$$F_x = 30\textrm{N}$$

Either of these is both *correct* and *complete*.

Your proposal, $\left|\vec{F}\right| = 30\textrm{N}$, is *correct* but **not *complete***, because it removes information (the sign of the component).

The notation you object to, $F=30\textrm{N}$, is *complete* but (arguably) not *correct*.

I don't see any value in considering $F=30\textrm{N}$ incorrect; I think of it as $F_x = 30\textrm{N}$ but without having to introduce a subscript to label a component that doesn't need disambiguation.  It is an inconsistency in the notation that should be explained when it's introduced, but I think it's an acceptable way to write vectors with a single component.

Comment: $|\overrightarrow{F}|$ is only talking about the magnitude of the vector, which is a perfectly sensible thing to talk about. It is perfectly valid to write it down, and explicit in what it dictates.

Comment: Sure, but the question was weather that should replace an expression of the entire vector, and in general it shouldn't.

Answer (score 7):

Force is indeed a vector. Technically you should write $|\overrightarrow{F}| = 30N$, however there is usually context given that let you omit this.

If you are working in one dimension, then the vector-like direction is all encapsulated in the sign once you've defined your coordinate system (e.g. -30N is 30N downwards.) Beyond that, it is typically just a shorthand to write $F = 30N$ as the magnitude of a vector $\overrightarrow{F}$ and the equation/problem will typically give you context into what is meant.

Sometimes you will see vectors that are written as $\overrightarrow{F} = (30N, 0, 0)$ (don't forget the units.) It's probably less common than something like $\overrightarrow{F} = 30N\hat{x}$, but if you are just learning this then expect all types to be thrown at you.

Answer (score 4):

Some people use $\mathbf{F}$ instead of $\vec{F}$ or even $\overrightarrow{F}$. I agree that often $F=\| \vec{F} \|$ is a convenient shortcut. So for example

> A force $\mathbf{F}=(10 \mbox{ N},0,0)$ has magnitude $\|\mathbf{F}\|=10 \mbox{ N}$.
>
> The components of $\mathbf{F}$ are $F_x = 10\mbox{ N}$, $F_y=0$ and $F_z=0$

So the subscript is used to designate which component, and the *italicized* variable indicates it is a scalar.

Comment: No worries :)..